# Non-negative, continuous function with integral

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, riemann-sum

Let there be an integrable, non-negative function $f$ in a range $[a,b]$.
If the integral $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ equals $0$, prove that $f(x)=0$ for every $x$ for which $f$ is continuous.

I have already tried to solve this problem, but i'd like some usefull input.

My solution:
Let there be a number $c$ in the range $[a,b]$, for which $f(c)>0$.
$f$ is continuous, so there should be a positive $d>0$ near $c$, so that $f(x)>0$ for every $x$ within $(c-d,c+d)$.
Now let there be a partition $P=\{x_{0},x_{1},....,x_{n}\}$ of the interval $[c-d/2 , c+d/2]$
with $x_{0}=c-d/2$ and $x_{n}=c+d/2$.

Let be $m_{i}=\inf \{ f(x): x_{i-1}\leq x\leq x_{i}\}$ for $i=1,2,...,n$. 
Therefore, $$L_{f,P}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} m_{i}(x_{i}-x_{i-1})>0\text{.}$$ 
However, we know that $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx=L_{f,P}=U_{f,P}=0$ and we have a contradiction. 
As such, there is no $c$ in $[a,b]$ so that $f(c)>0$, and so $f(x)=0$ for every $x \in [a,b]$.

Was my assumption of using the interval $(c-d,c+d)$ correct?

Comment: Your $P$ is partition of interval $[c-d/2,c+d/2]$, therefore $\int_{c-d/2}^{c+d/2}f(x) dx = L_{f,P}$. But the assumption is correct.

Comment: A minor amendment would be to take $c$ from the open interval $(a,\,b)$ rather than the closed interval $[a,\,b]$ to avoid $c=a$ or $c=b$.

Comment: What about the integral of [c−d/2,c+d/2]?
Can I use it the way I used the given integral? (Say that it equals 0 and as such the sums also equal 0)

Comment: A better candidate for duplicate is [Prove the integral of f>0 if f≥0 and f is continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)\gt 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/82839/3111), which deals with partial continuity (and which the above candidate was closed as duplicate to).