# Why is integral a proper inner product of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, inner-products, orthogonal-polynomials

I am aware that it may be a duplicate question, but I spent over an hour trying to find a proper proof and I failed. One may define inner product of polynomials $p, q$ as integral: $$\langle p, q \rangle = \int_a^b p(x)q(x) dx.$$ Inner product should satisfy following constraints:

- for each polynomials $p, q$: $\langle p, q \rangle = \langle q, p \rangle$ - this is quite obvious
- linearity - also easy to prove
- for each polynomial $p \neq 0$: $\langle p, p \rangle > 0$ - that's what troubles me

If I take any polynomial $p$, how can I be sure that the integral of $p^2$ is not $0$? I don't really see any argument that such a non-zero polynomial doesn't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove the integral of $f$ is positive if $f ≥ 0$, $f$ continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82839/prove-the-integral-of-f-is-positive-if-f-%e2%89%a5-0-f-continuous-at-x-0-and-f)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get the fact, that p^2 is >=0 and has at least one point x that p^2(x) > 0.

Comment: For real numbers squares are always greater than or equal to zero. For complex numbers your inner product is defined as the integral of $p(x)\overline{q(x)}$, which gives $|p(x)|^2$ for the product of $p$ with itself. A polynomial that is non-zero take some non-zero value somewhere. The square of a non-zero value, or the square of its norm in the case of complex polynomials, is non-zero.