$f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ and $\int_a^b f = 0$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, that $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ and that $\int_a^b f = 0$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

My attempt:
Let $\dot{\Pi}$ be a tagged partition of $[a, b]$. We have that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta_\varepsilon > 0$ such that $|\dot{\Pi}| < \delta_\varepsilon$ and
$|S(f, {\dot{\Pi}})| = |\sum_{i} f(t_i)(x_{i}-x_{i-1})| < \varepsilon$.
Assume $f(t_i) \neq 0$ for some $i$. Since we know that $x_i - x_{i-1} > 0$ (by the definition of the tagged partition) and $f(t_i) > 0$ then $f(t_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}) > 0$. Then $S(f, {\dot{\Pi}}) > 0$. By Archimedian property there is some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{m } < S(f, {\dot{\Pi}})$. Lets take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{m}$. Then $|S(f, {\dot{\Pi}})| \ge \varepsilon$ i.e. $f \not\in \mathcal{R}[a, b]$.
So, if $S(f, {\dot{\Pi}}) = 0$ we should have $f(t_i) = 0$ for all tags $t_i$. Since ${\dot{\Pi}}$ was arbitrary and the tags were arbitrary then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.
What is wrong with this logic? I know something is off since the next thing for me is to show that the proposition is not valid unless $f$ is continuous and I never used the continuity of $f$ in my proof.
An alternative - with the usage of the continuity of $f$ (again, seems to come to the same point and getting stuck)
Assume that $f$ is not identically $0$. Then there is some $c \in [a, b]$ such that $f(c) > 0$ for some $c \in [a, b]$. Since $f$ is a continuous function then there is some $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-c| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(c)| < \frac{f(c)}{2}$. So, $f(x) > f(c) / 2$ for $x \in [c-\delta, c + \delta] \cap [a, b]$.
Let ${\dot{\Pi}}$ be the tagger partition of $[a, b]$ that includes the sub-interval $[c-\delta, c + \delta] \cap [a, b]$. Let's denote that sub-interval $[x_{i-1}, x_{i}]$. Note that for any tag from this sub-interval we have $f(t)(x_i-x_{i-1}) > \frac{f(c)}{2}(x_i - x_{i-1})$.
Since $x_i > x_{i-1}$ then $f(t)(x_i-x_{i-1}) > 0$ and $S(f, \dot{\Pi}) > 0$.
At this point I would like to use the Archimedian again. However, people say that it is a circular logic. I just don't know...

Circular argument. Your $m$ already depedns on $\epsilon$ so you cannot take $\epsilon =\frac  1m$. Also, you did not prove $f(t_i)=0$ for every partition, so you don't get $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Basically the argument of continuity is the following. If $f(c)=k>0$ for an interior point $c$ then $f(x)>k/2$ for all $x\in[c-\delta,c+\delta]$ and the contribution to the integral is at least $2\delta k/2=\delta k>0$.

I would have used MVT for this, just like this post. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3468570/1188598

Guys, I am not seeking for an alternative (right) proof. I want to understand the fault in my proof. I am still struggling to do that.

@geetha290krm I am confused. Please, can you elaborate on my comment? My $m$ depends on $S(f, \mathcal{\dot{P}})$ and $S(f, \mathcal{\dot{P}})$ is not a function of $|\mathcal{\dot{P}}|$. I have used the definition to show that $S(f, \mathcal{\dot{P}})<\varepsilon$. Then I have tried to find a contradiction, by showing that if $f(t_i) = 0$ for some $t_i \in[a, b]$ then there is some $\varepsilon$ e.g. $\varepsilon_0$ such that we will get a contradiction.

To the original poster: In light of your comment, I have deleted my answer.

@Steen82 I am not seeking for an answer. I want to understand why this logic is faulty.

Deleted my previous comment, since I now understands what you are asking better. Your second attempt could be completed to show that any tagged partition containing the points $c-\delta$ and $c+\delta$ will have sum $\geq f(c)\delta.$
